# Random number in for loop C

Tags: c, for-loop, random

I need to generate 1000 random numbers inside a for loop.

my problem is that the random number generated is always the same. since im using time NULL to initiate the generator, why am i getting the same numbers? here is the code i used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LIMIT 30000

int main(){
  int i;
  srand((long) time(NULL));
  for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    int x = rand() % LIMIT;
    printf("%d\n", x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try it again now. Are you still getting the same numbers as you did when you posted this?

Comment: How do you know ? The loop does no printing.

Comment: Why the `&` in the `printf` statement?

Comment: Pointers should be printed with a %p format: `printf("%p",(void*) &x);`

Comment: Note: [`srand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand) requires an `unsigned int` for a parameter, so if you're casting the result of `time()`, at least use the correct type. Second, [`time()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time) is not provided in either of the headers you have included here; you need to `#include <time.h>`

Answer (score 1):

If you run the program multiple times during the same second, you will pass the same value to the generator as seed. You have to wait at least a second before trying it again.

This is because the `time` function returns the number of seconds since a specific time, and if called multiple times during the same second will return the same value.

Answer (score 0):

your code is right, but you forgot to include the time.h library.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> // <--- now it works
#define LIMIT 30000

int main(){

  int i;

  srand((long) time(NULL));

 for(i=0;i<1000;i++){

 int x = rand() % LIMIT;
 printf("%d",x);}
```